# Bootstrap column centers with img but not div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with centering within a Bootstrap column. I had a placeholder page using images (a white box with an image and text inside), that I needed to change to a square white div with the image added inside and the text manually added.

When I implemented it the 2nd way, all of a sudden my columns lost there centering.

Here are the codepens for the [centered one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epgJJp) and the [uncentered one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVZPVg).

Uncentered relevant HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 column-centered">
                <a href="../faq/category_3.html">
                    <div class="img-with-text">
                        <img src="img/Blue/VideoCollaboration-Blue.png"></img>
                        <p><b>Video Collaboration</b></p>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
```

Centered relevant HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 column-centered">
                <div class="img-with-text">
                    <a href="../faq/category_7.html"><img src="img/temp_image.png" alt="VideoCollaboration" /></a>
                </div></div>
```

I'd really like to avoid using offsets as that isn't really centering..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.img-with-text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.img-with-text{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: display: inline-block did it, hopefully one day these bits will be obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's because anchor tags are inline-block by nature, you will have to change it to block and do the following.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 column-centered">
    <a href="../faq/category_3.html" class="block text-center">
        <div class="img-with-text inline-block">
            <img src="img/Blue/VideoCollaboration-Blue.png"></img>
            <p><b>Video Collaboration</b></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

.inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}
.block{
  display: block;
}
```